# loading_animation is appearing unclear when app launches

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts

When I launch the app (create a new instance of application), the progress Bar image is unclear for some millisecond, but later it is appearing as expected :

[image]

I realize it is due my ViewPager in MainActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior=".behavior.QuickHideBehavior">

        <com.sample.android.contact.widget.ListenableTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I remove ViewPager, progress bar image is appearing at start as expected.

This is my imageView in Fragment of ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sample.android.contact.widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ContactsFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.sylversky.indexablelistview.widget.IndexableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription"
        tools:src="@drawable/loading_animation" />

</com.sample.android.contact.widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout>
```

When I use Handler post delay to set image, again it is appearing as expected :

```
 mHandler.postDelayed(() -> mProgressBar.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_animation), 0);
```

But without using Handler, it is unclear.

What could be the reason and how to resolve it?

And this is loading_animation :

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading_img"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Comment: make it clear with colors